# In process synchronization, what is a Monitor?

Tags: process

There are lots of information in the internet for Semaphore, Mutex, etc. But as far as I've searched, there isn't a clear info available on Monitors.

I know that a Mutex helps in Mutual exclusion between processes. A binary semaphore also does similar function. Then what is the use of introducing a new concept called Monitor.

What does it actually do that makes it so special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Monitor` is a more simple locking technique which allows resource lock between threads of a single process, while `Mutex` and `Semaphore` allows inter-process resource locking.